# Hint : I have 4 siblings

Tags: riddle, steganography

Last week I met this guy who asked me for my number. I told him that I will tell him only if he answers one of my questions first. He agreed.

> "What is the one thing common between China, North Korea and former Russia?".
>
> "Communism"
>
> "Are you sure?"
>
> "No, fingers crossed!"
>
> "Oh well. That's correct! My number is 555-0112. Call me."
>
> "Hey wait! what's your name?"
>
> I punched him in the face (p.s. very gently).
>
> "There, I told you my name"

What's my name??

Hint 1:

> I spelt out my name in the story

Hint 2:

> Think sign language guys!

Hint 3:

> 4 letter name

Comment: Kim Jong Un....

Comment: @Maurius Nope ! i hope you're joking!

Comment: 5 siblings instantly makes me think of vowels... oops that would make 6 of us

Comment: @humn Nope haha

Comment: I don't think that's a real phone number.

Comment: @BrianRisk yep i just gave it to confuse you guys!! Why you tried calling is it?

Comment: @starkgurl It might be a good idea to alter that fake phone number so it falls within 555-0100 to 555-0199, which is a special subset of phone numbers intended for fictional phone numbers in the USA.

Comment: @Nzall haha okay!!

Comment: Just want to point out that the communist fist (and most other fist/punch motions) appear more like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/Fist.svg/720px-Fist.svg.png which is with the thumb over the hand. This is the sign for S not A.

Comment: @humn Would that make Y a half-sibling? :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your name is:

> Arya

"What is the one thing common between China, North Korea and former Russia?".

> A - communist fist
>  [image: A]

"No, fingers crossed!"

> R - sign language
>  [image: R]

"Call me"

> Y - sign language
>  [image]

Punch

> A - (fist) sign language
>  [image: A]
>  The 5 siblings: Robb, Jon, Sansa, Bran, Rickon

Comment: The username is also relevant apparently

Comment: @styx the first "A" is not correct! :( think about the answer he gave!! ;))

Comment: Dunno if it's relevant, but "Are you sure" = "Are ya" = "Arya"

Comment: The communism fist could be the 'A'?  Although it's definitely more 'S'

Comment: @Joe haha i never thought of it!! but sureeee!

Comment: @starkgurl That was my first thought, but I failed my google search (only saw open hands when searched for USSR salute)

Comment: Is there any meaning behind the phone number?

Comment: @Wojowu nope, its just to confuse you guys! haha

Comment: @Styx Damn, you're good ...

Answer (score 5):

> "What" is your name, and your siblings are When, Where, Which, Why, and How.

Comment: Nope!! Thats not the answer but well tried!! :)

Answer (score 5):

> Rickon
> R - Russia
> I - I punched
> C - China
> K - Korea
> O - Oh well
> N - North
> The 5 siblings: Robb, Jon, Sansa, Bran, Arya

Phone number:

> 89457728 - If you match it with the corresponding position of the alphabet letters you get: HID EGG BH - not sure if related..

But I'm not sure how the story fits with the name

Comment: well, OP *is* a  Stark girl.

Comment: Nope!! Thats not the answer but well tried!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your name is

> Ryan

Although I'll have to admit, your hint was unbelievably helpful.

That's your name because

> Fingers Crossed is R
>
>  Call me - thumb and pinky extended - is Y
>
>  Fist is A
>
>  And I extrapolated to N.

Comment: Thanks for format help. How come my original format didn't work?

Comment: no :( thats not the answer but your verrryyyyy close! you just got one letter wrong!! Also i'll give you another hint! There are three letters in the name ---> one letter appears twice

Answer (score 3):

> Arya :) Using sign language for the 4 gestures mentioned, including communist fist

Athough it should be SRYS I suspect

Comment: Correct!! But explain!! haha :P

Comment: Yes, please [edit] to add explanation for why this answer fits the puzzle. Answers without explanation are liable to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Your name is:

> Palm or Palmer

And the five siblings are:

> The five fingers

Comment: nopeeeee!! :( Not the answer

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Talal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52974/19989)'s answer.

> Puncho
>  5 siblings = 5 fingers.
>  "I punched him in the face" hence Puncho.

.... or Chuck Norris.

Answer (score 1):

Only through the power of people being wrong could I know how to be right.

> SRYS

Five Siblings:

> The manner in which one makes a fist is important for five sign language letters.

Letters:

> Communist fist is the same as if you would punch someone. The only letter in sign language that looks like a proper punch is 'S'. R in crossed fingers, Y in 'call me' (making a phone gesture).

Comment: So close! See the top answer from Styx.

Answer (score 0):

Your Name:

> **Arya (StarkGirl).** In Game of Thrones one of Stark girl name was **Arya Stark**

Because it is a based on Sign Language:

> Letter A - "common between China, North Korea and former Russia?"
>
>  Letter R - "Fingers crossed"
>
>  Letter Y - "Call me"
>
>  Letter A - "I punched him in the face"

Comment: Please elaborate why this answer fits the puzzle.

Comment: @AJ Check it out.

Comment: Why all down votes?